# Requests Json throws an error in python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am running the below code, it runs fine in python 2.7 but throws an error in python 3.7 or 3.9 compiler.

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

username = "geeks_for_geeks"

user_info = requests.get('https://instagram.com/%s/?__a=1'%username, headers = headers)

print (user_info.json())
```

The error in python is below:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 13, in 
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: If you want to make more requests, look into instagrams official api: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api

Comment: Please show the complete error traceback and not just one line.

Comment: I have updated the complete code

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that you are getting back an error from the instagram site and the JSON decoder can't process the message (because it is not JSON).  try

```
print(user_info.text)
```

to see what the site is returning.

Comment: When I run the code in python 2.7 it pulls all data accurately..I ran the print(user_info.text) in python 3.7..it throws not-logged-in client-root"